# Selenium 2/WebDriver and Selenium Server - switching windows gives same HTML

Tags: selenium, window, automated-tests, webdriver, htmlunit

I've been using Selenium 2/WebDriver through Ruby 1.9.2, and directly through FireFox it works fine. I wanted to use HtmlUnit so it's faster and headless, so I'm trying selenium-server-standalone-2.17.0 as it should in theory require no code changes, and also I want to start using Java/groovy with HtmlUnit.

The problem is that half the time or more, a test fails because when I click a button and switch windows, the HTML (and title) in the new window is the *same* as the old one.

I added lots of debugging output to my function to try to narrow it down:

```
def switch_to_newest_window()
  assert(@driver.window_handles.size > 1, "only one window")
  print "switch to newest window, handles=#{@driver.window_handles}...\n"
  print "current handle: #{@driver.window_handle}\n"
  print "#{@driver.window_handles[0]}\n"
  print "#{@driver.window_handles[-1]}\n"
  print "title: #{@driver.title}\n"
  save_file("first.html", @driver.page_source)

  @driver.switch_to.window(@driver.window_handles[-1])

  print "new handle: #{@driver.window_handle}\n"
  print "new window title: #{@driver.title}\n"
  save_file("second.html", @driver.page_source)
end
```

And the relevant output is:

```
switch to newest window, handles=["36543124", "1755893858"]...
current handle: 1755893858
36543124
1755893858
title: Create FlowSet
new handle: 1755893858
new window title: Create FlowSet
```

So it's correctly switching windows, but the HTML is the same! If you diff first.html and second.html, there is no output.

I'm also a ruby noob so I may well be doing things the hard/slow way or incorrectly.

Other details: 
running on Windows 7. 
Selenium Server server-standalone-2.17.0
Server output when starting HtmlUnit session:
`13:03:12.292 INFO - Executing: [new session: {platform=ANY, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=false, browserName=htmlunit, nativeEvents=false, rotatable=false, takesScreenshot=false, version=}] at URL: /session)`

Thanks very much in advance for any help.

Joel

Comment: Maybe a timing issue? Try waiting a few seconds before switching windows.

Comment: I did have a 5 second delay after the switch in there but it made no difference to the frequency of failures. It was never a problem on Firefox, but then that is a different browser.

Comment: This: driver.window_handles[-1]
seems a little odd, I'd expect to see:
driver.window_handles[1]
Is that just how Ruby is?

Comment: The idea there is to grab the last handle in the list, to handle any number of windows, on the assumption that the newest window will be last in the list (not sure if that's true). In my test though there has only ever been 2 windows. Regardless, that bit of code works, as the debug output shows. Using [1] should also work, but -1 kind of means wrap around backwards and get the last element.

Comment: functionally equivalent to driver.window_handles[driver.window_handles.length]

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the explanation - sorry, that was a little off topic...